# jqGrid error in frozen columns

Tags: jquery, css, jqgrid

I have a grid with the first column frozen. When I move the horizontal scroll, this column in the grid´s header´s is frozen, but in the grid´s body, all the columns can be moved horizontally, the first column isn´t frozen. I´ve gone over my code a hundred of times and it´s fine. I don´t have any other css or javascript in my project, and it´s occurs in IE8, Firefox and Chrome. I´m working with the lastest version of jQgrid.

Here is my code:

```
jQuery("#single").jqGrid({
                    data : mydata,
                    datatype : "local",
                    height : 115, //Define el alto total del listado
                    width : 650, //Define el ancho total del listado
                    colNames : [ 'Index', 'Date', 'Code', 'Amount' ], //Nombres de las cabeceras de las columnas.
                    colModel : [ {
                        name : 'item_id', // Prop. name del modelo de datos
                        index : 'item_id',
                        width : 100,
                        sorttype : 'int',
                        align: 'center',
                        frozen:true
                    }, {
                        name : 'item_date',
                        index : 'item_date',
                        width : 450,
                        formatter : 'date',
                        formatoptions : {
                            newformat : 'd/M/Y'
                        },
                        datefmt : 'd/M/Y',
                        align: 'center'

                    }, {
                        name : 'item_cd',
                        index : 'item_cd',
                        width : 400
                    }, {
                        name : 'amount',
                        index : 'amount',
                        width : 400,
                        formatter: "integer", //Define el tipo de dato. Imprescindible cuando queremos crear una celda de totales. 
                        align: 'right',     //Alineación del texto dentro de la celda.
                        editrules : {
                            edithidden : true
                        },
                        editoptions : {
                            /*disabled : 'disabled',*/
                            size : '10',
                            maxlength : '8',
                        }
                    } ],
                    rowNum : 10,
                    rowTotal : 2000,
                    rowList : [ 5, 10, 20, 30 ],
                    loadonce : true,
                    mtype : "GET",
                    rownumbers : false, // Mostrar/ocultar el nº de fila.
                    rownumWidth : 40, // Ancho de la columna que muestra el nº de fila.
                    gridview : true,
                    pager : '#psingle', //Id de la capa que contiene el paginador.
                    sortname : 'item_id', // Columna inicial sobre la que realiza la ordenación. ini
                    viewrecords : true, // Muestra/Oculta  el mensaje de: "Mostrando 1 de..." 
                    sortorder : "desc",
                    editurl : './listado.html',
                    caption : "Tabla de datos editables", //Titulo del listado.
                    align: 'center',
                    //shrinkToFit : true,
                    footerrow : true, // Activa el pie del listado. Imprescible si se quiere visualizar.
                    userDataOnFooter : true,
                    edit : {
                        top : '100px',
                        left : '100px',
                        addCaption : "Add Record",
                        editCaption : "Modificar registro",
                        bSubmit : "Modificar",
                        bCancel : "Cancelar",
                        bClose : "Cerrar",
                        saveData : "Data has been changed! Save changes?",
                        bYes : "Yes",
                        bNo : "No",
                        bExit : "Cancel"
                    },
                });

                /* Botones de edición */
                jQuery("#single").jqGrid('navGrid', '#psingle', {
                    del : true,
                    add : true,
                    edit : true
                });

                /* Activa la funcionalidad de las columnas fijas. Se usa en combinación con el atributo "frozen:true"
                    en la columna. */
                jQuery("#single").jqGrid('setFrozenColumns');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of the problem is the bug in `setFrozenColumns` method of jqGrid. If you fill jqGrid from `datatype : "local"` or if just the grid is **already filled with data before calling of `setFrozenColumns`** the method `setFrozenColumns` works incorrect. As the workaround you can include the line

```js
jQuery("#single").triggerHandler("jqGridAfterGridComplete");
```

*directly after* `jQuery("#single").jqGrid('setFrozenColumns');`. I described the problem multiple times. After the post [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/upgrade-from-4-5-0-to-4-5-2-breaks-sorting-fixed-column-grids/#p28901) the bug is fixed in the code of jqGrid on [github](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid) (see the fix [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/7deae6c596db1442c32c12b88d0fdda9d9d5b3ae)). So you can remove the line later if you would use new version of jqGrid (version higher as the current 4.5.2).

Comment: Thank you very much!!!! I´ve been looking for something to fix this issue, but never found this answer and I was very worried about it. Sincerenly, thank you very much.

Comment: Is there any possibilities to last column as frozen column in jqGrid? @Oleg

Comment: here is that question link. sorry to post that question link here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27549268/jqgrid-frozen-column-freezing-column-to-right-end-of-the-grid @Oleg